# What preposition should be used with "course"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

**What is the right preposition for the following sentences:**

> Did you learn about things like that **in\on** your course.

> He is **in\on** the math course at college.

> I'll meet you **in\on\at** the course.

Comment: In would be correct. For the last one, technically you could use all of them, but they convey a different meaning.

Comment: Did this help? Or do you need clarification ?

Comment: Thanks. This helps but I need more clarification for the last one.